# Form OnClick ReferenceError: comment is not defined

Tags: forms, onclick

I'm trying to update my comment system and have run in to a snag. This is the error firebug is showing : ReferenceError: comment is not defined : comment(1000);

I'm at a loss to what the issue is - any ideas?

```
<div class="comment_heading">Leave a Comment</div>
<div class="post_comment">
<textarea name="txtpostcomment" id="txtpostcomment-1000" class="txtpostcomment"></textarea>
<button class="btnpostcomment" id="btnpostcomment-1000" onclick="comment(1000);" type="button">Send</button>
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="19vtyWh5iOpeKamXAQl3udqU9mMjnfKv/LnWr70M2jE=">
</div>

<script>
function comment(postid1)
{
    var txt =  $('#txtpostcomment-'+postid1);
    var btn =  $('#btnpostcomment-'+postid1);

    var comment1 = $(txt).val();
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $(btn).css('background-image', 'url(/comments/submit-busy.gif)');
    $(btn).attr('disabled', true);

    var dataString = 'commenting=1&postid=' + postid1 + '&comment=' + comment1 + '&name=' + name + '&token=' + token;

    .ajax({
        url: "/comments/submit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function()
        {
            $('.post_comment .error_msg').remove();
            $('.comment-list-'+postid1).prepend(msg.html);
            $(txt).val('');
        },
        error: function()
        {
            $('.post_comment .error_msg').value = 'Error - Please try again';
        }
    });

    $(btn).css('background-image', 'none');
    $(btn).attr('disabled', false);
    $(txt).attr('disabled', false);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved .. all I needed to change was :

```
.ajax({
```

To :

```
$.ajax({
```